How to stop microsoft oauth from forcing users to update password during consent granting flow?
My app for Microsoft Teams uses OAuth to get consent from users to use some permissions. But recently the consent process is forcing users to update their passwords after logging in before going to permission granting screen. Is there any way to stop or not force this password update step during the flow?
Following is the code that is used to start the consent flow.
class ConsentPopup extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log('consentPopUp initialized');

    microsoftTeams.app.initialize().then(() => {
      microsoftTeams.app.getContext().then((context) => {
        let tenant = context?.user?.tenant?.id; //Tenant ID of the logged in user
        let client_id = env.AZURE_APP_REGISTRATION_ID;
        let queryParams = {
          tenant: `${tenant}`,
          client_id: `${client_id}`,
          response_type: 'token',
          scope:
            'https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read https://graph.microsoft.com/TeamsActivity.Send offline_access',
          redirect_uri: window.location.origin + '/factory/auth-end',
          nonce: nanoid(),
        };

        let url = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?`;
        queryParams = new URLSearchParams(queryParams).toString();
        let authorizeEndpoint = url + queryParams;

        console.log(authorizeEndpoint);
        window.location.assign(authorizeEndpoint);
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{backgroundColor: "#ededed", height: "100vh", display: "flex", justifyContent: "center"}}>
        <h1 style={{alignSelf: "center"}}>Please wait...</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


The issue you're encountering with the forced password update during the OAuth consent flow in Microsoft Teams is likely related to security policies configured in your Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) tenant.
Could you please review Conditional Access policies in Microsoft Entra ID might be enforcing additional security measures, such as password updates. Review these policies to see if any changes have been made recently that could be causing this behaviour.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-sign-up-and-sign-in-policy?pivots=b2c-user-flow

if these policies are enforced at the Azure AD level, they cannot be bypassed programmatically in your application. You will need to work with your Azure AD administrator to understand and potentially adjust the policies that are currently in place.
